# Changing the address of ASMX service at runtime in windows forms

Tags: winforms, wcf, web-services, asmx

I have a code that will connect to a external ASMX service. THe requirement is i want to change the address of that service assuming the service remains the same.

```
       MySiteService.MySiteServiceSoapClient obj = new MySiteService.MySiteServiceSoapClient();

       // here i might change the address like  "http://test.com/test.asmx"

        bool IsAuthorised = false;

        try
        {
             IsAuthorised = obj.IsAuthorised(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Service Unavailable. Please try again later..");
            return;
        }
```

Right now when i add a service the address are stored in three file something like .disco etc.

Comment: @mamoo I add a service using "ADD SERVICE REFERENCE" wizard in win forms. I have no knowledge of wrappers etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the URL of your service like so:

```
obj.Url ="http://whatever.com/where.asmx";
```